# Makinkg dynamic DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I'm try making a dynamic `DropDownList` this way:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategory" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    onselectedindexchanged="CategoryDropList_SelectedIndexChanged" />
</form>

void DropListInit() 
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dic.Add("1","apple");
    dic.Add("2","banana");
    ddlCategory.DataSource = dic;
    ddlCategory.DataTextField = "value";
    ddlCategory.DataValueField = "key";
    ddlCategory.DataBind();
}

protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    DropListInit();
}

protected void CategoryDropList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    ddlCategory.SelectedValue = ddlCategory.SelectedValue;
}
```

And i find out that in doesn't work without this strange expression `ddlCategory.SelectedValue = ddlCategory.SelectedValue;` So, what this expression means? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the DropListInit to `Page_load` as the following;

```
protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if (!IsPostBack)    
    {
        DropListInit();
    }
}
```

Remove this;

```
ddlCategory.SelectedValue = ddlCategory.SelectedValue;
```

Should be fine.